# How do I push an object onto the dataLayer

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

I'd like to use object in the atalayer. I've followed the developer docs and they show a flat data model. I'd like to push a lead object and update it as a user enters info into a Lead form.
with company, size and location, key and value.

```
dataLayer.push({'event': 'company_on_blur'});  //on leaving a company field
dataLayer.push('lead.company', '<company>');
dataLayer.push('lead.size', '<company-size>');
dataLayer.push('lead.size', '<company-location>');
dataLayer.push('lead.key', '<value>');
```

Is there a way to push all this data as a structured lead object?

```
 onclick="dataLayer.push({  
    // lead data object 
 });
```

also how can I modify just one property of an object once it is pushed

```
dataLayer.push({'event': 'company_on_blur'});  //on leaving a company field
dataLayer.push('lead.company', '<company>');   //update the value in the object
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can push several values at once with dataLayer.push. It will become something like this:
dataLayer.push({
'event': company_on_blur,
'lead.company': company,
'lead.size': company-size,
'lead.**location**': company-location,
'lead.key': value
});

To update a value in object on a given event - just use the event as a firing trigger (Fire tag X when custom event equals company_on_blur).

If your idea is to get a fields values from a form and send them to GTM - it's easier to create the variables for the values extractions, create the trigger company_on_blur and fire a tag for collecting the data. You can use also a form submit click as a trigger instead of leaving the field, if you are ok to collect these only for people which clicked the submit button. This way you will collect all data at once.